# Include css and js from an engine to a rails app created with rails plugin new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I just created a rails plugin with "rails plugin new pluginname --mountable".

Now I would like my app in test/dummy to access the js and css in my app/assets/javascripts and app/assets/stylesheets directories... I would like this process to be "automatic"(so no copy/paste of files from these directories to my test/dummy...)  because I would like to release this plugin for people to use it and it should be as much easy to use as possible.

Thank you in advance for your help

Gnagno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset pipeline will find any asset that is inside of an engine. If you have a file `app/assets/javascripts/foo.js` and in your host application's `application.js` has:

```
//= require foo
```

It will include your asset in the combined `application.js`.

If you want to automatically include your file you will have to add to `config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults]` but this was replaced with using comment requires in the asset pipeline.

Comment: isn't it possible to make some configuration at plugin level so that the js and css from the plugin will be included in every page of the hosting application?